# C#MVC Datetime changing format error

Tags: c#

when i want to change my datetime format i take error.I use this code on view:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.enddate, new { @Value =((DateTime)Model.enddate).ToString(" dd/MM/yyyy"),@class = "input-xlarge datepicker"})
```

but when i execute Model.enddate is null so i take this error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not
>   set to an instance of an object.

Can you help me.

My english is not very well :(

Comment: you can check on null when set value

Comment: [What is a `NullReferenceException` and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1):

If the model.enddate is legitimately null you could set the datatype to nullable in the model - DateTime? enddate

And you could add the DisplayFormat Attribute to the property

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
 public DateTime? enddate{ get; set; }
```

Comment: where i should write this?

Comment: you should add the attribute above the fields in you Model class containing the enddate property

Answer (score 0):

Check that from you controller you send an instance of the model with data, it seems that property enddate is null.

Comment: Its true enddate is null i said this but it should null because i take enddate's value on view.

Comment: so you when you try `enddate.ToString` - you get this error, don't do that  that :-)

Comment: and yoy pass the instance of the object to the view like    return View(model);

Answer (score 0):

You date seems to be nullable, format it only when a value is provided :

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.enddate, new { @Value =(Model.enddate.HasValue ? Model.enddate.Value.ToString(" dd/MM/yyyy") : ""),@class = "input-xlarge datepicker"})
```

Comment: it still take same error.Object reference not set an instance of an object

Comment: Then maybe Model it self is null. I think MarkP is right, use DisplayFormatAttribute.